# Given the ODE $(x+y+1)dx + (2x+2y+1)dy =0$, determine whether $e^{x+y}$ is an integrating factor or not.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the ODE $(x+y+1)\,dx + (2x+2y+1)\,dy =0$, determine whether
>   $e^{x+y}$ is an integrating factor or not.

I know we can multiply it to the ODE and check the exactness ($\partial M / \partial y = \partial N / \partial x$ for $M\,dx + N\,dy = 0 $ ODE) but the solution given to me was as follows :

For ODE $M\,dx + N\,dy = 0$,
if for some function $v(x,y)$, if $\frac{(\partial M/\partial y) - (\partial N/ \partial x)}{N \cdot (\partial v/ \partial x) -M \cdot (\partial v/\partial x)}$ is again a function of $v$, say $f(v)$ then the integrating factor is $e^{\int f(v) dv}$

$e^{x+y} $ being a function of $x+y$, we take $v=x+y$ and 
$\frac{(\partial M/\partial y) - (\partial N/ \partial x)}{N \cdot (\partial v/ \partial x) -M \cdot (\partial v/\partial x)}$  turns out to be $\frac{-2}{x-y}$ which is a function of $v$ so the integrating factor is $\frac{1}{(x+y)^2} \neq e^{x+y}$ and hence $e^{x+y}$ is not an integrating factor.

End of solution.

Now the last line has clearly been established assuming the fact that there exists only one integrating factor of function $v$. So I want to know whether we have any such theorems available or not.

Comment: perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2830247/is-there-any-theorem-on-uniqueness-of-integrating-factor-for-inexact-ordinary-di) post might help

Comment: How do you get that $\frac{-2}{x-y}$ is a function of $v=x+y$?

Comment: With $v=x+y$ you get $0=(v+1)dv+vdy$ which separates with the integrating factor $\mu=\frac1v$ and has the first integral $F=v+\ln |v|+y$. Multiplying the first integrating factor with (for $v>0$) $e^F=ve^{v+y}$ gives a second integrating factor $e^{v+y}=e^{x+2y}$ which gives $e^F=(x+y)e^{x+2y}$ as first integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation is wrong cause if $v=x+y$ the total derivative is $dv=dx+dy$ and you forgot to substitute either $dx$ or $dy$ in the original ODE

I chose $dy=dv-dx$ thus:
 $$(x+y+1)dx+(2x+2y+1)dy=0 \implies (v+1)dx+(2v+1)(dv-dx)=0\\ -vdx+(2v+1)dv=0$$

Then $$\frac {\partial M}{\partial v}=-1\qquad \& \qquad \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=0$$

$$P(x)=\frac{M_v-N_x}{N}=\frac{-1}{2v+1}\qquad \text{No depends of x} $$
$$P(v)=\frac{N_x-M_v}{M}=-\frac1v\qquad \text{Depens only on V}$$

Our Integrating factor is $$\mu(v)=e^{\int P(v)}=-\frac1v$$ in fact we prove that the integrating factor depends of $x$ and $y$, $$\mu(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x+y}$$

If you need to, you can solve the ODE from here.